# Use kubectl or other ansible module like command, script to run shell command in a pod

Tags: python, kubernetes, ansible

I have a playbook with kubectl command, when I want to run this command it cannot avoid quotes and understand this directory not exist

```
--- 
    - 
      hosts: localhost

      vars_files: 
        - vars/main.yaml 


      tasks:     
        -
         shell:
           cmd: |
               kubectl exec -it -n {{ namespace }} {{ pod_name }} -- bash -c \"clickhouse-client --query "INSERT INTO customer FORMAT CSV" --user=test --password=test < /mnt/azure/azure/test/test.tbl\"
         register: output2
```

Here is the error:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "kubectl exec -it -n ch-test04 chi-test-dashboard-sharded1-dashboard03-3-0-0 -- bash -c \\\"clickhouse-client --query \"INSERT INTO customer FORMAT CSV\" --user=test --password=test < mnt/azure/azure/test/test.tbl\\\"\n",
    "delta": "0:00:00.002088",
    "end": "2020-04-23 13:30:00.456263",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "kubectl exec -it -n ch-test04 chi-test-dashboard-sharded1-dashboard03-3-0-0 -- bash -c \\\"clickhouse-client --query \"INSERT INTO customer FORMAT CSV\" --user=test --password=test < mnt/azure/azure/test/test.tbl\\\"\n",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 2,
    "start": "2020-04-23 13:30:00.454175",
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: cannot open mnt/azure/azure/test/test.tbl\": No such file",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: 1: cannot open mnt/azure/azure/test/test.tbl\": No such file"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

So when I put this command in a python script ansible still manuplate quotes and got the same error. I already tried escape/quote but I think the problem is when I use '<' character after query where from insert data and ansible cannot understand entire command not finished yet. But I am not sure how can I tell with the correct way.Thanks

Comment: Try replacing the places where you have `\"` with `"` and replace `"` with `\"`. I.e. switch them around, I think you might have the escaping backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You quoted the wrong characters; you want the **interior** quotes to be escaped, or sidestep that entire mess and use alternate characters for the outer from the inner:

```yaml
- shell: |
    kubectl exec -i -n {{ namespace }} {{ pod_name }} -- bash -c 'clickhouse-client --query "INSERT INTO customer FORMAT CSV" --user=test --password=test < /mnt/azure/azure/test/test.tbl'
```

Comment: thank you. I was so confused trying tons of combination and what it tricks me, the output of task is negative, so last time I check in clickhouse server and I have seen there is already data in related table. But in playbook output it is giving tty error even it is succesfull. Thanks though.       
  
     "rc": 0,
        "start": "2020-04-24 09:13:08.055648",
         "stderr": "Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file",
        "stderr_lines": [
            "Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file"

Comment: ah, yes; remove the `-t` option since it is running under ansible, there is no associated tty for it to allocate -- you may even be able to remove the `-i` also, since there is similarly no stdin that the exec would need

Comment: yes, thanks again I remove **-t** and error has gone. I appreciate you

Comment: Please do consider "accepting" the answer, to indicate to others that you found it to be successful. It also helps those going through the queue of new questions to know they don't need to look at this one anymore